# Using ActiveRecord caching library in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, caching, memcached, heroku

I'm studying how to use caching in Heroku for my Rails app. HTTP cache powered by Varnish is superb and I'll use it in all pages without user info but I also want to use a kind of ActiveRecord caching with Memcached using "high livel" plugins such as cache_fu or cache-money...but it seems that Heroku supports only the memcached gem (http://docs.heroku.com/memcache) and it's a very low level Memcachad API...

Do you have any other solutions?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout http://github.com/teich/heroku-cache-money. I'm about to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

The ActiveSupport module has [built-in cache store support](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html) that can be backed by memcached. [This Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/115-caching-in-rails-2-1) has the details.

Comment: Hi John,
thx, I know the ActiveSupport module for cache/memcached but I want to use (in Heroku) on of plugins that help me to transparently bind ActiveRecord objects through memcached...